# Proof Rényi entropy is non-negative

Tags: entropy, quantum-information

The Rényi entropy is defined as:
\begin{equation}
S_\alpha = \dfrac{1}{1-\alpha}\log(\text{Tr}(\rho^\alpha))
\end{equation}
for $\alpha \geq 0$. This can be rewrited in terms of $\rho$ eigenvalues, $\rho_k$, which verify $0 \leq \rho_k \leq 1$, as:
\begin{equation}
S_\alpha = \dfrac{1}{1-\alpha}\log(\sum_k \rho_k^\alpha)
\end{equation}
How can one proof rigurously that $S_\alpha \geq 0$? I am having trouble with this proof eventhough it seems pretty easy.

Comment: Try to show that $S_\alpha   \ge S_{ + \infty }  =  - \max_k \log \rho _k  \ge 0$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9nyi_entropy#Inequalities_between_different_values_of_%CE%B1

Comment: @Gary I had that idea from Wikipedia as Tuvasbien pointed out, but I have not been able to perform that limit at $\alpha \rightarrow \infty$ :(

Answer (score 1):

Let $\|\rho\|_{\infty}=\sup_{k\geqslant 0}\rho_k$, then
$$ S_{\alpha}=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\log\left(\sum_{k\geqslant 0}\left(\frac{\rho_k}{\|\rho\|_{\infty}}\right)^{\alpha}\right)+\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\log\|\rho\|_{\infty} $$
Let $p$ be the number of $k\geqslant 0$ such that $\rho_k=\|\rho\|_{\infty}$ (there is a finite number of such $k$ because $\rho_k<\|\rho\|_{\infty}$ for $k$ large enough). We thus have
$$ S_{\alpha}=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\log\left(p+o(1)\right)+\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\log\|\rho\|_{\infty} $$
Taking the limit as $\alpha\rightarrow +\infty$ gives $\lim\limits_{\alpha\rightarrow +\infty}S_{\alpha}=-\log\|\rho\|_{\infty}$ and thus $S_{\alpha}\geqslant -\log\|\rho\|_{\infty}\geqslant 0$ for all $\alpha\geqslant 0$.

Comment: Sorry, how did you arrive at $S_\alpha \geq -\log\|\rho\|_\infty$? In particular, why is the first term of $S_{\alpha}=\frac{1}{1-\alpha} \log (p+o(1))+\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha} \log \|\rho\|_{\infty}$ nonnegative?

Comment: The inequality $S_{\alpha}\geqslant -\log\|\rho\|_{\infty}$ comes from the fact that $\alpha\mapsto S_{\alpha}$ is decreasing. As for your second question, $p\in\mathbb{N}^*$ so either $p\geqslant 2$ and thus $\log(p+o(1))\geqslant 0$ for $\alpha$ large enough (this means that this term is negative), or either $p=1$ and $\log(p+o(1))$ can be either positive or negative depending on the sign of $o(1)$. Anyway this is not important because this term goes to $0$ as $\alpha\rightarrow +\infty$.

Comment: Ah I see - I thought that you were able to deduce that $S_\alpha$ was nonincreasing within this argument but I see now that that comes from a separate argument.